# Can anyone help me use applescript to check my email?

Tags: gmail, applescript

I'm scripting a code in applescript that:

1. goes to gmail
2. logs in
3. displays a dialog saying if I have any new emails
4. has a yes or no button on that dialog that "yes" will open that email or "no" to log out of gmail. I also dont want gmail to open the new email if it is a FWD.

So far I've finished step 2. (logging in)
This is my code so far

```
tell application "Safari"
    open location "www.gmail.com"


end tell



tell application "System Events"
    set texttosay to "Sample Text"
    activate "Email login"
    display dialog "Username" default answer "white:wave:"

    set texttosay to the text returned of the result

    activate application "Safari"
    keystroke texttosay
    delay 1


end tell
tell application "System Events"
    set texttosay to "Sample Text"
    activate "Email login"
    display dialog "Password" default answer "white:wave:" with hidden answer
    set texttosay to the text returned of the result

    activate application "Safari"
    keystroke tab
    delay 1
    keystroke texttosay
    delay 1
    keystroke return
    delay 5
    activate "Email login"




end tell
```

Comment: Just a suggestion: don't try to do this via AppleScript/Safari user interface scripting. Why? Because you're re-inventing the wheel, and not a very solid one. Gmail changes its interface – your script won't work. Same thing could happen with next version of Safari. Moreover, your script is very slow (the delays alone are 8 seconds so far). Why not try one of the excellent email client programs out there? Apple Mail, Mozilla Thunderbird, Sparrow (ad-supported free version), younameit - are all way faster and far more convenient than anything you could accomplish via AppleScript.